# Element td rendered by component not explicitly closed

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I have the code below and sometimes my pages are not rendered properly :

```
 <div id="logout" style="text-align:right;">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h3>
                <h:outputText value="Hello #{myBean.usr.name} #{myBean.usr.surname}" style="color:black;"/>
            </h3>
            <p:commandLink action="#{myBean.quit}" immediate="true">
                <h:outputText value="Quit"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </h:panelGrid>
</div>
```

I have a warning  :

`WARNING: HTML nesting warning on closing h3: element td rendered by component : [...] not explicitly closed`

I know it's just a warning but I want to resolve the problem to be sure this is not the cause of bad display.

Comment: I found a solution removing `columns` properties of `panelGrid` and removing `h3` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `<h3>` tag and style the `<h:outputText>` using a CSS class. Or try enclosing the section in `<h:panelGroup>`.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h3>
            <h:outputText value="Hello #{myBean.usr.name} #{myBean.usr.surname}" />
        </h3>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <p:commandLink action="#{myBean.quit}" immediate="true">
        <h:outputText value="Quit"/>
    </p:commandLink>

</h:panelGrid>
```

[Laying Out Components with the h:panelGrid and h:panelGroup Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cos6/index.html)

Comment: Tried it but don't change anything ! Thanks.